# How to dynamically reference resources in the R.drawable folder in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following code for my Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Games game = gameList.get(position);
    holder.awayTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fortyers);
}
```

The above works perfectly but I am hard coding the image that will be displayed. What I really need is to get the background image from the game list and I am looking to do something like this:

```
 holder.awayTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.game.getaBackground());
```

> But that causes an error

How can I dynamically set the imageView's background resource?

### UPDATE:

I have attached a screenshot of the desired effect.

Each week the schedule will change so the list will always be different depending on the week selected.

[image]

Game constructor:

```
public Games(DataSnapshot game) {

    this.AwayTeam = game.child("AwayTeam").getValue().toString();
    this.AwayId = Integer.parseInt(game.child("AwayId").getValue().toString());

    this.HomeTeam = game.child("HomeTeam").getValue().toString();
    this.HomeId = Integer.parseInt(game.child("HomeId").getValue().toString());

    this.aBackground = game.child("aBackground").getValue().toString();
    this.hBackground = game.child("hBackground").getValue().toString();

}
```

Comment: Put a `getaBackground()` method on `Games` that returns a drawable resource ID.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have the method, how do i return a drawable resource id?

Comment: Somewhere along the line, you need to be able to associate a team with suitable resources, such as the team name and the helmet image. So, maybe a `Games` has two `Team` objects, one each for `home` and `away`. A `Team` could have a `getTeamName()` that returns the string resource ID of the team name, and a `getTeamHelmet()` that returns the drawable resource ID of the helmet. Somewhere (a `League` singleton?) you would create the master roster of teams (e.g., new Team(R.string.team_name_phl, R.drawable.team_helmet_phl);`). Now, your `Games` has access to drawable IDs for both helmets.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of String that will contain the id of your drawables, keep them in the order synced with the position and then get the id as per the position from the list to pass while setting the drawable.

If it's something reused in multiple places and the order is consistent, you can also go for an Enum to get the drawable id in terms of a certain key of your choice. You might need to figure the key using a when condition as per position if it's really dependant on the position.

Hope that works!

Comment: I have added an update and screenshot, so I do not think your suggestion will work for me, as the list will differ from week to week as its based on a weekly schedule.

Comment: If it's that dynamic, you might want to get your images remotely where you can return different images based on the week. Any simple database service like a firebase would allow you to store certain names for your images and you can keep the same images in a cloud of publically accessible location. Then use any simple 3rd party library to load the image using the names you get from your DB along with a static URL where your images are accessed from.

Comment: understood, so there really isnt any way to do it using the `drawable` resource tho correct?

Comment: I don't think that would be something efficient if your use-case requires you to have a different image every other week!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Games` class should be a model/data class; so you can have an int member field that can store drawable id for each instance of this class, and create getter & setter:

```
public class Games {

    private int myDrawable;

    public int getMyDrawable() {
        return myDrawable;
    }

    public void setMyDrawable(int myDrawable) {
        this.myDrawable = myDrawable;
    }
    
}
```

Whenever you construct the `Games` objects, you can set the drawable image id using `setMyDrawable(R.drawabe.foo)`.. Probably you can modify the `Games` constructor to accept an int parameter that you can set `myDrawable` to.

Then in RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Games game = gameList.get(position);
    holder.awayTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(game.getMyDrawable());

}
```

UPDATE:

```
public class Games {

    private int homeTeamImage, awayTeamImage;

    public int getHomeTeamImage() {
        return homeTeamImage;
    }

    public void setHomeTeamImage(int homeTeamImage) {
        this.homeTeamImage = homeTeamImage;
    }


    public int getAwayTeamImage() {
        return awayTeamImage;
    }

    public void setAwayTeamImage(int awayTeamImage) {
        this.awayTeamImage = awayTeamImage;
    }

    public Games(DataSnapshot game, int homeTeamImage, int awayTeamImage) {

        //... rest of code

        this.homeTeamImage = homeTeamImage;
        this.awayTeamImage = awayTeamImage;

    }

}
```

But in terms of OOP, I'd suggest that you can have a Team class that has either team properties, like image, name, .... etc. and the `Games` class can be the controller of the game, not building the team instances.

Comment: I have that to some extent. the part i am confused is with the comment you are referring to in my constructor, `setMyDrawable`. I updated my question to reflect my constructor.

Comment: @Learn2Code Just wondering whether you want to set both home and away images the same way

Comment: Yes, that would be ok.

Comment: I am trying the following but always get 0 as the id. `Integer drawableId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(aTeam, "R.drawable", getPackageName);
` but as i said it does not seem to be working?!

Comment: @Learn2Code Please have a look at `UPDATE` section.  You should get the drawable id just with `R.drawable.my_resource_id`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that might help you is using `getIdentifier` from the string. For this what you have make a background string name same as the one in your resource. e.g if you want to show `ic_menu_camera` then your `aBackground` should be the same string.

Example game class:

```
public class Game {

    String aBackground;

    public Game(String aBackground) {
        this.aBackground = aBackground;
    }

    public String getaBackground() {
        return aBackground;
    }

    public void setaBackground(String aBackground) {
        this.aBackground = aBackground;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this. Read inline comments to understand in detail.

```
//set the background name that you want same as name in your drawable folder
        // without any extension .png or .xml. Just name should be there
        Game game = new Game("ic_menu_camera");
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        //get the id by name using this
        /*  @param name The name of the desired resource.
             * @param defType Optional default resource type to find, if "type/" is
             *                not included in the name.  Can be null to require an
             *                explicit type.
             * @param defPackage Optional default package to find, if "package:" is
             *                   not included in the name.  Can be null to require an
             *                   explicit package.
             * 
             * @return int The associated resource identifier.  Returns 0 if no such
             *         resource was found.  (0 is not a valid resource ID.)
             * */
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(game.getaBackground(), "drawable",getPackageName());
        // then set that id to your image
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not make things too complicated. Just use a simple approch. Using `HashMap` should do just fine.

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Cincinnati", R.drawable.red_striped_helmet);
map.put("Cleveland", R.drawable.red_helmet);
map.put("New York", R.drawable.blue_helmet);
map.put("Chicago", R.drawable.dark_blue_helmet);
map.put(homeTeam, homeId);
...
holder.awayTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(map.get("New York"));
// holder.awayTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(map.get(homeTeam));
```