# Android Studio: Drawable Folder adding subdirectory or create new folders issue

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am trying to do one of two things

1. add subdirectory to the drawable folder, as I have away team and home team that need to be in separate folders.

It seems that it can not be done.

So I am trying the following where I create 'top' folders like aTeam and hTeam by adding New Resource Directory and give them the name of aTeam and hTeam with the resource type of drawable.

The folders are created in the project folder structure but they are not being displayed in the android studio project and I can not reference them?

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Use assets directory. In it you can create your subfolders.

Comment: "I have away team and home team that need to be in separate folders" -- why? For example, in the images in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67950264/115145), you only need one helmet per team, as you can mirror it for the other orientation. Even if you do not want to do that, you can have "left" and "right" images in one folder (e.g., `helmet_phl_left.jpeg` and `helmet_phl_right.jpeg`).

Comment: @CommonsWare I didnt think of that, so ill use the same image and just setup the layout with android:scaleX="-1" to flip it. Thx!